# I am trying to send id through form but submit does not work

Tags: php

I created a category editing page on my site.
But that I'm trying to submit the category I want to edit the ID was not sent through form.
**I'm unable to pull the ID.**

edits_cat.php

```
  <!--Form-->
    <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
     }
          ?>
 <form action="edit_cat.php" method="post">
<label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">Select Categorie</label>
 <select name="edit" style="width:auto;" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-1" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
                                                                            
<?php
 while ($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
 echo "<option name='id' value='{$result['id']}'>{$result['cat']}</option>";
 }
 ?>
 </select>
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Select a category</button>
</form>
<!--END Form-->
```

edit_Cat.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = $mysqli->con->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` where id = '$id'");
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: You send the data using `POST` method, you need to pass it inside the `form`, currently you are passing the data in the `url` `?id=...`, try to add `hidden` input with the name `id`

Comment: @BurhanKashour You mean hidden input and its name will be id?

Comment: Posted an answer check it out :)

Comment: @DanielBarda replace `<form action="edit_cat.php" method="post">` with `<form action="edit_cat.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">`

Comment: @BurhanKashour Hi,
This is what I did from the beginning but once I do this code the submit does not respond.

Comment: what about sending the id without a form such as a like button (when it's toggled should send the id of the post to increment their likes counter) ?!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
<form action="edit_cat.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
```

With this:

```
<form action="edit_cat.php" method="post">
```

And then Add `Hidden Input` Inside your `form`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `id` via URL, so you can access it by `$_GET['id']`. If you want to access via `$_POST['id']`, you need to add a hidden input in your form.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

Comment: If he will use `$_GET` he needs to change the form `method` as well!

Comment: Hi,
I did as you said.
But as I move on to the next page I try to pull the id but without success.
I'm trying to pull the category data but I got an error.
```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\www\login\panel\edit_cat.php</b> on line <b>272</b><br />

@BurhanKashour
@Chhaileng

Comment: @DanielBarda Right now you have a problem with your `query` not the `category id`

Comment: @BurhanKashour

He does not recognize the id
When I add to url
edit_cat.php? id = 1
He manually recognizes it.
The problem with getting the id for the next page I go through.
From edits_cat to edit_cat

Comment: @DanielBarda Then you need to pass it with `url` and get it using `$_GET['id']`

Comment: That's why I opened the post.
 Because I could not get it through url.
@BurhanKashour

Comment: @DanielBarda in the 2nd page just change `$id = $_POST['id'];` to `$id = $_GET['id'];` and make sure that the `id` represent in the url `?id=123`

Comment: @BurhanKashour Hi,
I tried it.
It does not work.

You can see my code.
I put up in the post the code of the new php.